# Is it considered "bad style" when not ending php function with `return` statement?

Tags: php, return

I want to load Google fonts in the head-section of my page using a php-function.

My `<head>`-area looks like this:

```
...
<?=Class->loadGoogleFonts($fontsfile)?>
...
```

Now I have the feeling, that I have to end the `loadGoogleFonts` function with a return-statement. But when I do this, there will be a "1" displayed (because of the `<?=`).

Is it bad style to avoid the return-statement?

Comment: What? A `return` doesn't make sense in this code snippet. It looks like `loadGoogleFonts` itself already returns since you echo the return value.

Comment: functions do NOT need to return a value to be valid functions

Comment: Okay, so I thought every function should always end with a return-statement. I take it this is a missunderstanding of mine?

Comment: if you don't care about the result why are you using `<?=` instead of `<?php`?

Comment: Your code snippet isn't a function, it's calling a function.

Comment: because I want to use a "one-liner". I thought you do this with `<?=`

Comment: Piece of advice (no snark intended in following comment): if you have all this doubts about functions and proper use of `<?=` I suggest you take another look at the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having no return is not bad style in general.
Having `<?= .. ?>`is bad style if you don't want to display anything. Simply use `<?php .. ?>`.

Having no return can be bad style if some code paths return a value, but other code paths do not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use `<?php ... ?>` then.

Answer (score 1):

Return values are *optional*. The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) states:

> If the `return` is omitted the value **NULL** will be returned.

So even if you don't return anything yourself, there will be a returned *thing*, although that thing will be an *empty nothing*.

---

In your example:

> ```
> <?=Class->loadGoogleFonts($fontsfile)?>
> ```

If there is nothing returned then the value of `Class->loadGoogleFonts($fontsfile)` will be `null`.

Therefore because it's `null` your use of `<?=` is pointless. `<?php echo null;?>` does nothing.

If it is *sometimes* `null` and *sometimes* a value, then you should always return something to avoid this ambiguity. For example; say the return is the number of fonts loaded (`3`) by the method. If no fonts are loaded then the method should explicitly return `0` not `null`. You should make your returns consistent types.

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
<?php ... ?>
```

instead of

```
<?= .. ?>
```